# How to extend AuthGaurd Class Imported from 'nest-keycloak-connect'

Tags: typescript, nestjs, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am using **nest-keycloak-connect** in nestjs
and I want to create my own class extends from AuthGuard class for some custom functionality

I tried and it works well

```
  @Injectable()
  export class KeycloakAuthGuard extends AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const value = super.canActivate(context);
        const [request] = extractRequest(context);
        console.log(' ++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++ ', request.user); //getting user here

        // Some Custom functionality here..... like call any external request

        return value;
    }
  }
```

**But I need to add a constructor so that I can use some services here like HttpService
Can anyone please help me out how can I?**

```
constructor(private http: HttpService) { super() //contructor requires 4 arguments }
```

if I give constructor params like

```
constructor(
        private http: HttpService,
        @Inject(KEYCLOAK_INSTANCE)
        private keycloak: any,
        @Inject(KEYCLOAK_CONNECT_OPTIONS)
        private keycloakOpts: any,
        @Inject(KEYCLOAK_LOGGER)
        private logger: Logger,
        private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    ) {
        super(
            keycloak,
            keycloakOpts,
            logger,
            reflector
        );
    }
```

I encountered this error

> **Class 'KeycloakAuthGuard' incorrectly extends base class 'AuthGuard'.
> Types have separate declarations of a private property 'keycloak'.**

**class AuthGaurd** Code you may find here:
https://github.com/ferrerojosh/nest-keycloak-connect/blob/master/src/guards/auth.guard.ts

**nest-keycloak-connect package**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-keycloak-connect

Comment: what if you use [property-based injection](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection) instead?

Comment: Was my answer able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what I got from the library author is

**Rename the constructor properties since they will conflict with the superclass.**

```
constructor(
  @Inject(KEYCLOAK_INSTANCE)
  private keycloak1: any
  @Inject(KEYCLOAK_CONNECT_OPTIONS)
  private keycloakOpts1: any,
  @Inject(KEYCLOAK_LOGGER)
  private logger1: Logger,
  private readonly reflector1: Reflector
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Typescript when you include a modifier for a constructor property (eg. public, private) you're using a short form syntax that also defines a class member and assigns the constructor argument to that member.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(private readonly thing: number) { }
}
```

is short form for

```js
class MyClass {
  private readonly thing: number;

  constructor(thing: number) { 
     this.thing = thing;
  }
}
```

So if you just remove the `private` modifier in front of `private keycloak: any,` you'll simply receive the value as a constructor argument which you can then pass to `super` without it colliding on the existing class member from the base class